# Put text to the right of figures

Tags: floats, numbering, captions

How can I display text to the *right* of figure, vertically centered? "Caption" is only displaying text below it, as it seems to me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the [sidecap](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sidecap) package and the `c` (centered) option for `\sidecaptionvpos`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{sidecap}

\sidecaptionvpos{figure}{c}

\begin{document}

\begin{SCfigure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=7cm]{name}  
  \caption{text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text}
\end{SCfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the captions should always appear to the right, you can use the `rightcaption` package option:

```
\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}
```

Another option, using `\capbeside`, from the powerful [`floatrow`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) package this time:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\floatbox[{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={right,center},capbesidewidth=4cm}}]{figure}[\FBwidth]
{\caption{A test figure and its caption vertically centered side by side}\label{fig:test}}
{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{name}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Comment: What if I am using `\documentclass[t,ignorenonframetext]{beamer}`? How can I put the caption on rhs?

Comment: SCfigure works perfectly with the oxford bioinformatics style! cheers