# How can I reference lstlisting

Tags: code

I just got the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\geometry{paper=a4paper, left=24mm, right=23mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    xleftmargin=.1\textwidth, 
}

    
\begin{document}
\blindtext

 \begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
def generate_grid(data, basemap, delta=1):
    grid = {
        'lon': np.arange(-180, 180, delta),
        'lat': np.arange(-89.9,89.9, delta) 
    }
    grid["x"], grid["y"] = np.meshgrid(grid["lon"], grid["lat"])
    grid["x"], grid["y"] = basemap(grid["x"], grid["y"])
    return grid 
\end{lstlisting}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

The output looks like this
[image]

But I want there to be a number on the left side, because I have several lstlisting and I want to refer to them how do I do that?

[image]

(sorry for my drawings)

Comment: yes that only partly answers my question, because I don't want the title to say listing and I want the reference number on the left side

Comment: You should treat a listing as a type of graphics, don't try to place something that liiks like an equation number on the side. That will only confuse the readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I combined [`listings` and `sidecap` - Side captions for listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125106/listings-and-sidecap-side-captions-for-listings) and [Put text to the right of figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49979/put-text-to-the-right-of-figures) to get the caption to the center right of the listing. Then to add the parentheses the `labelformat=parens` was used, and to remove the word 'Listing' I used an empty `name=` option to `\DeclareFloatingEnvironment`.

Note that the label and caption need to be set in the regular way (so not as `lstlisting` options) and the parentheses around the `\ref` statement need to be added manually because `labelformat` does not extend to the output of `\ref`.

MWE:

```
% sources:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125106/listings-and-sidecap-side-captions-for-listings
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49979/put-text-to-the-right-of-figures

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\geometry{paper=a4paper, left=24mm, right=23mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    xleftmargin=.1\textwidth, 
}
\usepackage[wide]{sidecap}                                      
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[placement={!ht},name=]{listing}
\captionsetup[listing]{labelformat=parens}
\sidecaptionvpos{listing}{c}
\makeatletter
\makeatother

    
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{SClisting}
 \begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
def generate_grid(data, basemap, delta=1):
    grid = {
        'lon': np.arange(-180, 180, delta),
        'lat': np.arange(-89.9,89.9, delta) 
    }
    grid["x"], grid["y"] = np.meshgrid(grid["lon"], grid["lat"])
    grid["x"], grid["y"] = basemap(grid["x"], grid["y"])
    return grid 
\end{lstlisting}
\caption{}
\label{lst:grid}
\end{SClisting}
\blindtext
The grid algorithm is described in (\ref{lst:grid}).
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer but my code makes the one on the side a bit thick, how can I make it look like yours?

Comment: I edited the question shortly after answering to use the normal font for the (1). To do so I removed all the options for `\usepackage{caption}`, so instead of the first versions where I just copied the line `\usepackage[font=footnotesize,
    format=plain,
    labelfont={bf,sf},
    textfont={it},
    width=10pt]{caption}`, I removed all the font=, format= etc stuff and used just `\usepackage{caption}` (17th line of code).

Comment: Ok I found my mistake! I have already created \usepackage[labelfont={bf,sf},font={small},%
  labelsep=space]{caption} defined! But I want to keep the figure captions bold but the code number should not be bold.

Comment: You can set separate caption options per type, see the caption package manual for details.

Comment: Im new in Latex, how should i do this?

Comment: See section 3.2 of the manual (http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption.pdf) on page 19. You can move the settings from `\usepackage` to a separate `\captionsetup` command where you specify that the options should apply only to figures and not to anything else such as listings.

Comment: Hi I have another question I have now used \captionsetup{style=base}. However, the numbers on the right side are indented differently, but I don't understand how I can make the numbers appear on one level on the right side.

Comment: @Weiss it would be better to ask a separate question about this (i.e., with the Ask Question button) because it is a different issue. To make that question more clear you could try to generalize it a bit, i.e., ask about a caption for a figure instead of for a listing (if the issue indeed also applies to figures, otherwise you can use the listings example from this question again).

Comment: I wrote a new question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/659252/numbering-in-the-right-margin-and-in-brackets

Answer (score 2):

With [cleveref](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) and its macro `\crefname`, you can create a custom counter and assign a label to it--I have added *python code* for demonstration. Then, with `minipage`, you could create some space at the right-hand side of the code for a number; I have done it with `minipage`, which by default aligns a number in the middle.

In the code below, I also suggest a custom environment `pythoncode` with an optional parameter if for some reason you would like to increase/decrease indentation. Of course, you could parameterise any other option of the environment.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paper=a4paper, left=24mm, right=23mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstnewenvironment{pythoncode}[1][.1]{%
  \lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    xleftmargin=#1\textwidth,
    language=Python,
  }}{}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref} 

%%% New counter controlling python code numbers
\newcounter{lst}
\renewcommand*{\thelst}{(\arabic{lst})}   % Format the counter (currently (<number>)
\crefname{lst}{python code}{python codes} % Adds a label when referencing
\AtBeginEnvironment{minipage}{\noindent}  % Removes indentation at the beginning of each minipage


\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-3em}%
  \refstepcounter{lst}\label{lst:a}%
  \begin{pythoncode}
def generate_grid(data, basemap, delta=1):
grid = {
  'lon': np.arange(-180, 180, delta),
  'lat': np.arange(-89.9,89.9, delta) 
}
grid["x"], grid["y"] = np.meshgrid(grid["lon"], grid["lat"])
grid["x"], grid["y"] = basemap(grid["x"], grid["y"])
return grid
  \end{pythoncode}%
\end{minipage}{\raggedleft\thelst\par}

\blindtext

\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-3em}
  \refstepcounter{lst}\label{lst:b}%
  \begin{pythoncode}
def foo(x):
    return x**2
  \end{pythoncode}
\end{minipage}{\raggedleft\thelst\par}

\Cref{lst:a} and \cref{lst:b}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution is more or less what the `caption`, `newfloat` and `sidecap` packages do 'under the hood', but it is nice to see it implemented without those packages (+1).

Comment: @Marijn Thanks. I thought to post a comment but realised I wouldn't have enough space to suggest an alternative approach.