# Edit caption numbering

Tags: sidecap

Hi I have the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\geometry{paper=a4paper, left=24mm, right=23mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm}
%Abbildungen
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[list=true,listformat=simple]{subcaption} %Mehrere Bilder in einer figure
\usepackage[justification=raggedright]{caption}
                                    %Zentrierte Beschriftungen
\usepackage{float}                  %H-Figure Typ
\usepackage[labelfont={bf,sf},font={small},%
  labelsep=space]{caption} 
\usepackage{rotating}


\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    xleftmargin=.1\textwidth, 
}
\usepackage[wide]{sidecap}                                      

\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[placement={!ht},name=]{listing}

\sidecaptionvpos{listing}{c}
\makeatletter
\makeatother

    
\begin{document}
\blindtext
(\cite{pykrige}). 
\begin{SClisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
from traceback import print_tb
import numpy as np 
from pykrige.ok import OrdinaryKriging
from pykrige.kriging_tools import write_asc_grid
import pykrige.kriging_tools as kt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
\end{lstlisting}
\captionsetup{style=base}
\caption{}
\label{lst:einf}
\end{SClisting}
\blindtext
\begin{SClisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
def load_data():
    dflm = dfl
    return dflm

def get_data(dflm):
    return {
        "lons": dflm['Longitude'].values,
        "lats": dflm['Latitude'].values,
        "values": dflm['ValueHeight'].values
    }

dflm = load_data()
base_data = get_data(dflm)
\end{lstlisting}
\captionsetup{style=base}
\caption{}
\label{lst:laden}
\end{SClisting}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{Unbenannt.PNG}
    \caption{these captions should remain as they are}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and the following output
[image]

However, I want the numbers on the right edge to be in a plane and surrounded by a bracket. I know I have to change the `\captionsetup{style=base}`snipped, however I don´t know in which way

The difficulty:I have illustrations in the same work, so the defintition of the caption for the code must be such that it only affects the code and the captions of the illustrations remain as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** after a follow-up question.

This code will put the caption on the right border with the brackets.

It uses     `\usepackage[margincaption,leftbody]{sidecap}`  and defines a new caption format to position the caption and add the brackets.

[image: c]

With `\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=myformat}` `myformat` is applied only to the  lstlisting's captions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\geometry{paper=a4paper, left=24mm, right=23mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm, showframe} % added showframe <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
%Abbildungen
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[list=true,listformat=simple]{subcaption} %Mehrere Bilder in einer figure

%Zentrierte Beschriftungen
%\usepackage{float}                  %H-Figure Typ
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage[labelfont={bf,sf},font={small},labelsep=space]{caption} 
\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{\hspace*{\dimexpr-2\marginparsep -\marginparwidth-3ex\relax}[#1]}% added <<<<<<<<<

\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=myformat}% apply only to lstlisting

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    xleftmargin=.1\textwidth, 
}
                 
\usepackage[margincaption,leftbody]{sidecap}  % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[placement={!ht},name=]{listing}

\sidecaptionvpos{listing}{c} % in here
\begin{document}
    \blindtext
    (\cite{pykrige}). 
\begin{SClisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
from traceback import print_tb
import numpy as np 
from pykrige.ok import OrdinaryKriging
from pykrige.kriging_tools import write_asc_grid
import pykrige.kriging_tools as kt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
\end{lstlisting}
    \caption{}
    \label{lst:einf}
\end{SClisting}
    \blindtext
\begin{SClisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
def load_data():
    dflm = dfl
    return dflm

def get_data(dflm):
    return {
        "lons": dflm['Longitude'].values,
        "lats": dflm['Latitude'].values,
        "values": dflm['ValueHeight'].values
    }

dflm = load_data()
base_data = get_data(dflm)
\end{lstlisting}
        \caption{}
        \label{lst:laden}
    \end{SClisting}

\begin{figure}[hb!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image}
    \caption{these captions should remain as they are}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\end{documen
```

Comment: but i have illustrations, so for the code sections i only have to make the change

Comment: I have updated my question ;), however a big thanks for your idea

Comment: @Weiss Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, I still want to know how I can set the distance to the right side? I am still new to latex and do not understand everything yet.

Comment: @Weiss Thank you for feedback!
 (1) Read the caption doc on how to define a new custom style (2) Try `\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{\hspace*{<space>} [#1]}` with different negative spaces starting with `0pt` (3) Google in this site `\dimexpr`